# Getting org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am currently learning Spring. I am in dependency injection topic and I am trying to practice injecting Reference obejct into setters through DI. But I am facing a issue.

Client.java

```
package bean.driver;

import bean.Car;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String files[] = new String[]{"engine.xml","car.xml"};
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(files);

        Car car = (Car) applicationContext.getBean("car");
        //car.printdata();
        car.printcardata();

    }
}
```

Car.java

```
package bean;

public class Car {

    private String carname;
    private Engine engine;
    private int cost;
    private int yearofRelease;
    private int maxspeed;
    private Inventory inventory;
    private String engineversion;


    /*Car(String carname, Engine engine)
    {
        this.carname = carname;
        this.engine = engine;
    }*/
    Car(String name,Engine engine,Inventory inventory, int maxspeed)
    {
        this.carname = name;
        this.maxspeed = maxspeed;
        this.engine = engine;
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }

    public void setCost(int cost)
    {
        this.cost = cost;
    }
    public void setYearofRelease(int yearofRelease)
    {
        this.yearofRelease = yearofRelease;
        System.out.println(engine.getEngineversion());
    }
    /*public void setEngine(Engine engine2)
    {
        this.engineversion = engine2.getEngineversion();
    }
    public String getEngineversion()
    {
        return engineversion;
    }*/

    public void setEngineVersion(Engine engine)
    {
        this.engineversion = engine.getEngineversion();
    }
    public void printdata()
    {
        System.out.println(carname + " "+ engine.getModel() +" "+cost+" "+yearofRelease);
    }

    public void printcardata()
    {
        System.out.println("Carname:-"+carname+"\n"+"Cost:-"+cost+"\n"+"MaxSpeed:-"+maxspeed+"\n"+
                "Year of Release:-"+yearofRelease+"\n"+"Engine model:-"+engine.getModel()+"\n"+
                "No of Units:-"+inventory.getNoofinitalunits()+"\n"+"Engine Version:-"+engineversion);
    }

}
```

Engine.java

```
package bean;

public class Engine {

    private String model;
    private String engineversion;

    Engine(String model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void setEngineversion(String engineversion) {
        this.engineversion = engineversion;
    }

    public String getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }

    public String getEngineversion()
    {
        return engineversion;
    }
}
```

car.xml

```xml
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
        "https://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>


    <bean id="car" class="bean.Car">

        <!--dependecy injection through constructor of secondary type-->
         <constructor-arg ref="engine"/><!-- we are passing object as a reference -->

         <constructor-arg>
         <ref bean="inventory"></ref>
        </constructor-arg><!-- passing object as a refernece -->

        <!-- pass object as a value -->

        <!--<constructor-arg>
            <bean class="bean.Engine">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value>S10</value></constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>-->

        <!--dependency injection through constructor of primary type-->
        <constructor-arg value="Suzuki"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>230</value>
        </constructor-arg>

        <!--dependency injection through setters of primary type-->
        <property name="cost" value="10"/>
        <property name="yearofRelease">
            <value>1994</value>
        </property>

        <!--dependecy injection through setter of secondary type-->

        <property name="engine" ref="engine"></property>


    </bean>

    <bean id="inventory" class="bean.Inventory">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>1000</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="engine2" class="bean.Engine">
        <constructor-arg value="S88"/>
        <property name="engineversion" value="V11"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

engine.xml

```xml
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
        "https://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>

    <bean id="engine" class="bean.Engine">

        <constructor-arg value="S88"/>
        <property name="engineversion" value="V11"/>


    </bean>

    <bean id="engine2" class="bean.Engine">

        <constructor-arg value="S88"/>
        <property name="engineversion" value="V11"/>


    </bean>

</beans>
```

Error

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=51693:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\Spring-2\target\classes;C:\Users\chris\Downloads\spring-beans-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\chris\Downloads\spring-context-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\chris\Downloads\spring-core-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\chris\Downloads\spring-expression-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\chris\Downloads\commons-logging-1.2.jar bean.driver.Client
V11
Feb 06, 2022 1:53:20 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'car' defined in class path resource [car.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'engine' of bean class [bean.Car]: Bean property 'engine' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'car' defined in class path resource [car.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'engine' of bean class [bean.Car]: Bean property 'engine' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1744)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:95)
    at bean.driver.Client.main(Client.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'engine' of bean class [bean.Car]: Bean property 'engine' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:243)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:432)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:266)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1740)
    

Process finished with exit code 1
```

See the property name is engine and also in xml document I have mentioned as engine only. But still getting the error.

Comment: Do not longer use the old xml configuration. Use only the new annotation based way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but any idea why the above error came.

Comment: I can't see any setter for `engine` in `Car` *Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?*

Comment: Oh ok got it, please tell me  if we set <property name="engine".../> then will spring look for setengine(). Is it case sensitive like will it also accept setEngine()?? Thanks for the help.

Comment: It must be setEngine.  Because of java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Xml configuration is old ,its better you read about new xml configuration.
You should change your xml file like below code.

Car.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="car" class="com.example.stackoverfollw.Car">

        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="220"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="engine"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="inventory"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="3" value="650"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="engine" class="com.example.stackoverfollw.Engine">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="V11"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="inventory" class="com.example.stackoverfollw.Inventory">
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

Engine.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="engine" class="com.example.stackoverfollw.Engine">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="v22"/>
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

For more information about bean

- [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_definition.htm#:~:text=A%20bean%20is%20an%20object,seen%20in%20the%20previous%20chapters](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_definition.htm#:%7E:text=A%20bean%20is%20an%20object,seen%20in%20the%20previous%20chapters)
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But can you please let me know why I am getting the above error. I am trying to set the values, but the last value "engine" object is not getting set.

Comment: *Xml configuration is old ,its better you read about new xml configuration.* you mean new `annotations based`?